# Mysql count frequency of every value with grouping by another values (two dimensional table)

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by

Maybe my English is not good enough to formulate the header (you're welcome to edit it and make more understandable) or it's because I'm googling different forms of it all day, but the task sounds very easy. Say I have a simple unsorted table about publications of 2013

```
+----------+--------------+-----------+
| company  |   magazine   |   month   |
+----------+--------------+-----------+
| Google   | NatGeo       | march     |
| Intel    | Playboy      | january   |
| Google   | NatGeo       | february  |
| IBM      | LinuxJournal | february  |
| IBM      | NatGeo       | march     |
| ...      | ...          | ...       |
```

, etc. So every listed company has articles in different magazines. I cannot figure out how to count numbers of all articles in each magazine grouping by company to get this:

```
+--------+--------+---------+--------------+-----
|        | NatGeo | Playboy | LinuxJournal | ...
+--------+--------+---------+--------------+-----
| Google |   2    |   0     |      1       |
+--------+--------+---------+--------------+-----
| IBM    |   1    |   2     |      1       |
+--------+--------+---------+--------------+-----
| Intel  |   0    |   3     |      0       |
+--------+--------+---------+--------------+-----
| ...    |        |         |              |
```

It describes that Google had two articles in NatGeo, one in LinuxJournal and zero in Playboy during last year. Number of companies is unknown, as well as number of magazines. Not all companies have articles in same magazines or in all magazines. Of course, names of magazines and companies are unique.

If you really know how to easily do it using only SQL*, you can later give me a piece of advice, where to put another possible clause `WHERE month='...'`, but it's not really important.

---

*I can do it only using two queries and PHP loop

**EDIT** One angry guy assumed I didn't even try to do it by myself, so I have to present you a small part of my unsuccessful attempts. I started with basics:

```
SELECT company, COUNT(magazine) FROM `journals` WHERE magazine='somemagazine' GROUP BY company
```

It works predictably fine

Then I've tried to add at least one more magazine.

```
SELECT j1.company, COUNT(j1.magazine) AS SomeMagazine, COUNT(j2.magazine) AS AnotherMagazine FROM `journals` j1, `journals` j2 WHERE j1.magazine='SomeMagazine' AND/OR j2.magazine='AnotherMagazine' GROUP BY j1.company
```

The idea was to query the same table twice. Surprisingly it also works, but multiplies all results (both columns have the same values in rows). I knew it's a wrong direction, so I've tried to left-inner-outer join my first table with the same query but another magazine. No luck. I've always got longer table (it just puts more rows to the end) or multiplied values. I've tried to `UNION` queries changing magazine's name every next string. Again no luck.

Yep, I knew about all this `@` and `@@` stuff and @eggyal's solution is likely correct, but I still wonder if it's possible to perform such an easy action with easy statements... maybe for two certain magazines for a start.

Comment: Come on. Have a go... - although you are, to some extent, confusing data retrieval, and data display!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP has not made any effort to make an attempt.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO how do you know it? Are you living with me in my room? I spent two days googling and trying to `join`, `union`, etc. simple query `SELECT company, COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE magazine='...' GROUP BY company` but I couldn't do it even for two magazines

Comment: Roll your mouse over the down vote icon next to your question. Questions mush show a minimal research effort.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO so, do you have any ideas how to solve it or you can only downvote?

Comment: I removed the downvote since you've edited your question. Thanks!

Comment: How can Intel and IBM be mentioned in Playboy magazine?

Answer (score 3):

This operation is known as a "*pivot*", which (unlike some other RDBMS) MySQL does not support natively.  You have a couple of options:

1. Simply group the data in the database layer and pivot it within your presentation layer (this is what the MySQL developers believe is the "correct" approach, and hence their justification for omitting native pivoting features from MySQL itself):

   ```
   SELECT   company, magazine, COUNT(*)
   FROM     my_table
   GROUP BY company, magazine
   ```

   (One can outer join with the cross of a list of magazines and companies, if you require every possible combination from the database).
2. Make a query for the magazine names, and use that to build an SQL command that fetches the desired data (you can either do this within PHP, or within MySQL itself via [user variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/user-variables.html) and [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)):

   ```
   SET @@group_concat_max_len = 4294967295;

   SELECT CONCAT('
            SELECT   company,'
          , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(' 
                     SUM(magazine=',QUOTE(magazine),')
                       AS `',REPLACE(magazine,'`','``'),'`'
            )), '
            FROM     my_table
            GROUP BY company
          ')
   INTO   @sql
   FROM   my_table;    -- one might instead select from a magazines
                       -- table (if one exists), and save on DISTINCT

   PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
   EXECUTE stmt;
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

   SET @sql := NULL;

   SET @@group_concat_max_len = 1024;
   ```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to use prepared statements in that program, but phpMyAdmin returns
`MySQL said:
#1172 - Result consisted of more than one row`

Comment: sorry, still `#1243 - Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE`. Can you, plz, extend you first point. How can I do it for only 2 magazines?